# Start a DB service on a remote host

Tags: ansible

In Ansible playboook, I am getting an error while running the start service module, as I want to start the DB on a remote host. I am new to Ansible.

I came up with this:

```
- name: This starts the MySQL Database in the host
  hosts: dbserver
  connection: ssh
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  tasks:
  - name: Start the DB in host
    become: yes
    become_user: root
    service:
      name: mysql
      state: started
```

I am getting this error:

> fatal: [10.138.12.67]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not find the requested service mysql: host"}

Comment: Service for mysql server is usually known with the name mysql**d** (for *daemon*). And a simple note: there is no need to set `become_*` options at task level if they are already set at play level.

Answer (score 0):

@Zeitounator is correct just adding a right playbook which can be used:

```
- name: This starts the MySQL Database in the host
  hosts: dbserver
  become: yes
  become_user: root

  tasks:
  - name: Start the DB in host
    service:
      name: mysqld
      state: started
      enable: yes
```

Here is link where you can check Syntax: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_module.html